# How to fetch the date of the file from the folder in UNIX Shell Script?

Tags: shell, date, unix, unix-timestamp, less-unix

I am beginner to Shell Script.
Just want to know how to fetch date of the file from the properties in the UNIX Shell Script?
When I put 'ls -lrt' , could fetch the date where as for last six months we could see only date and time but year is not populated.

### Output:

Jan 10 2022 
Feb 20 2022
Jan 11 15:10

For third one, year is not populated.

I tried the following commands '''--full-time''', '''--time-style''' and '''stat''' but its not supporting in my UNIX version
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no standard command for that; you need to specify the target OS.

Comment: Best to be sure `stat` isn't already on your machine. you could do `find / -name 'stat' -ls` but it may take a long time to complete. If you can't find it then, 2nd best is to search for an installable version of `stat` for your OS. 3rd case would be to find the source code and compile it. Good luck.

Comment: Other than stat , is there any other solution

Comment: the most portable way to get the modification timestamp would be `perl -le 'for (@ARGV) {print ((stat($_))[9])}' file1 file2 ...`